# Detect Minimization / Focus Utility Bar Component And Resize Workspace Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, utility-bar

Apparently [there is no method](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226538/how-to-detect-minimize-action-on-a-utility-bar-item) (at this point) for detecting when the  utility bar item minimize / maximize event is fired.

I could potentially use jQuery to listen for a click on the button, but everything I'm reading advises *against adding any jQuery event listeners* like `onClick` event, and the "minimize" button's classes may change regardless...

Does anyone have any thoughts?

[image: example minimize / toggle utility bar in lightning console]

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, there's no events for utility bar components, but we do have the ability to get a hold of the current state of the item, which allows us to poll for changes:

```
<lightning:utilityBarAPI aura:id="utilitybar" />
```

...

```
setInterval($A.getCallback(function() {
  component.find("utilitybar").getUtilityInfo().then(function(result) {
    if(result.utilityVisible) {
      // we're currently open
    } else {
      // we're minimized
    }
  });
}), 1000); // check every second
```

You can also check panelHeight and panelWidth for the current dimensions of the panel. Store the results in an attribute if you want to check the differences.

Try not to poll too frequently, as it may cause user interface lag. I'm considering this to be kind of a last-resort sort of deal, because it shouldn't be necessary, but this is as close as we get.

Comment: If SF is opened in multiple browser tabs, and each tab is polling then thing can get super crazy

Comment: @PranayJaiswal It would be so simple to have events for this, but ... well, it didn't happen. I hate polling, because this is 2018, not 1996, but maybe they'll sort it out sooner or later.

Comment: I am checking the Transactions tab in lightning inspector. Two events `ltng:interaction [synthetic-click:one-utilityBarItem--panelMinimized]` and `ltng:interaction [synthetic-click:one-utilityBarItem--panelOpened]` are fired. I dont know if they can be capture.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal The events we're allowed to listen to are documented. If they're not documented, we can't use them. I haven't tried these ones in particular, but I have tried others. They simply never come through.

Comment: It looks like these interactions are stored in database, and can be queried in EventLogFile . EventLogFile  does not support triggers yet.. if they did we could do much more by firing platform event and listening on UI amd then doing fancy stuff

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact use case, I'll say that sometimes re-thinking the problem yields an answer.

Let's say on open, you want the UI to populate with certain attributes; and on close, you want that UI to revert to its default state. The utility bar API does include a [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_onUtilityClick.htm) for tracking when a utility item is opened:

```
const eventHandler = (clickInfo) => {
   const {utilityId, panelVisible} = clickInfo;
   if(utilityId === <myUtilityId>){
      if(panelVisible){
         //my util item was opened
         if(criteriaMet){
           doOpenActions();
         }
      } else{
         //my util item was closed
         //caveat: the minimize button is not detected
         doMinimizeActions();
      }
   }
};
        cmp.find("utilBarApi").onUtilityClick({ 
                eventHandler 
        });
```

Since we cannot know for certain that a user *didn't* minimize the component, on open we can instead reset to default state first *then* populate the UI conditionally.

```
const eventHandler = (clickInfo) => {
   const {utilityId, panelVisible} = clickInfo;
   if(utilityId === <myUtilityId>){
      if(panelVisible){
         //my util item was opened
         //reset to default state
         doMinimizeActions();
         if(criteriaMet){
           doOpenActions();
         }
      } else{
         //my util item was closed
         //caveat: the minimize button is not detected
      }
   }
};
        cmp.find("utilBarApi").onUtilityClick({ 
                eventHandler 
        });
```