# Raising an event on utility bar pop out

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, utility-bar, event-handler

This is somewhat an update of the question raised [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226538/how-to-detect-minimize-action-on-a-utility-bar-item). The only answer for this question does work, but I am hoping that a better solution has appeared in the years since that post. Salesforce is very protective of its elements and any attempts to attach an event handler to the popOut button have not worked.

When a user pops out the utility bar modal, a new instance is created, so any of the data they entered in the docked modal will be lost. My goal is to give them a warning that they are about to lose data before allowing them to pop the modal out. [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_methods_lightning_utilityBarAPI.htm) are the available utility bar methods, and none of them allow me to know when a modal is about to be poppedOut.
The closest option [`isUtilityPoppedOut()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_isUtilityPoppedOut.htm) is too late to warn the user that they are about to lose data.

Thank you

Comment: You could just store the data in sessionStorage, no?

Comment: @sfdcfox that's a good idea. I'll give that a shot, thank you.